# React Hook useCallback() after validation?

Tags: react-hooks

So I have read some threads on here that offer examples, but ones that I can't seem to wrap my head around for my use case.

I have a form with a Submit button. I want to validate one of the text field values, and only then do I want to execute the useCallback. Here is the submit handler, handleSubmit that is triggered from the form's Submit button being hit.

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    async event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const data = await fetch('/video/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          identity: username,
          room: roomName
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(res => res.json());
      setToken(data.token);
    },
    [roomName, username]    
  );
```

And here is the validator that I want to invoke. Only if the return value is true do I then want to execute the useCallback.

```js
function IsAuthCodeValid() {
    var hashedAuthCode = roomName.split('').reduce((prevHash, currVal) =>
                (((prevHash << 5) - prevHash) + currVal.charCodeAt(0)) | 0, 0).toString();
    if (authCode === hashedAuthCode) {      
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  };
```

What's the quickest way to accomplish this? I am new to React Hooks frankly, so I am just starting to dig in. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just call `handleSubmit` when you think it should be called. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: The Lobby where the information is provided is where I see {handleSubmit}, and I can't figure out how to evaluate the IsAuthCodeValid() function and only if true then execute the handleSubmit hook. Here's the Lobby source code --> [link]https://github.com/philnash/twilio-video-react-hooks/blob/master/src/Lobby.js

Comment: you will need to change `Lobby` such that the form `onSubmit` will call `isAuthCodeValid` and if it's valid, it will call `handleSubmit`

Comment: That's where I'm having the problem. I can't seem to call the handleSubmit hook if the isAuthCodeValid comes back as true. The React Hooks environment won't allow this.

Comment: please share the code where you actually call `isAuthCodeValid`

Comment: It's in the form's onSubmit function. But then my isAuthCodeValid function cannot call the React Hook for handleSubmit. The handleSubmit Hook has to be top-level and can't be called from a basic Javascript function. Perhaps I'll try to implement some field validation and add that logic to the handleSubmit.

Comment: unless you share that piece of code, there is not much I can do

Comment: Here it is... <form onSubmit="IsAuthCodeValid()"> And my IsAuthCodeValid() function cannot in turn call a React Hook. The error returned is --> Failed to compile
./src/VideoChat.js
  Line 31:3:  React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: `isAuthCodeValid` is not call `handleSubmit` also, where is `handleSubmit` defined? Can you share a complete example??

Comment: That was provided in my first post in the thread.It's okay, I will figure it out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you could create a function that calls your validation function (`IsAuthCodeValid`) and then calls your submit function (`handleSubmit`).

```js
const formSubmit = (event) => {
  const isValid = IsAuthCodeValid();
  if (isValid) {
    handleSubmit(event);
  }
};
```

Your form now calls this function

```html
<form onSubmit={formSubmit} ...
```

---

To fix the `React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally` problem, check if you are defining your `handleSubmit` function after an `if` or any other condition.

One of the rules of hooks is that they shouldn't be called conditionally, and if your component has a condition that may "return before" that hook definition, it isn't allowed.

You can learn more about hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html